# Find intersection and ETA

Tags: math, coordinates, intersection, points

I have 2 coordinate points A,B and I want to know the formula to calculate the intersection point if that exist.

Let's say I have an airplane at Lat: 42.68543 Lon: 16.9880 moving at 196 deg with 430km/h and another one at Lat: 36.72348 Lon: 20.76236 moving at 269 deg with 670km/h

1) I want to calculate the intersection point (if exist)

2) If intersection exist I need to know the estimate time that each craft needs and the distance to the intersection point

Can you help me with a Java example on how can I find it?

Comment: I think you have to specify what you mean by "moving at x degrees". Do you mean they are traveling on orthodromes (great circles = lines of shortest distance) or on loxodromes (lines of constant bearing)?

Comment: Hi Curd, i mean they are moving in any direction from 0 - 359, 0 deg is north

Comment: That's clear; but if you say a plane is traveling a given direction, it is not clear whether the direction will stay constant with respect to north during the whole trip (loxodrome) or whether the direction applies only at the starting point and the plane continues on a great circle (orthodrome).

Comment: Hi Curd. For this i get a new updated variable about position and direction every minute. The point is that i want to check if there is any possible collision on that planes at the spicific time. After one minute i will check again. The updated degres are a value from 0-359 so i dont know which option is better. Do you have any suggest on this? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

If you have position vectors `A=(xa,ya)` and `B=(xb,yb)` and corresponding velocities `Va` and `Vb`, you are trying to solve `A+s*Va=B+t*Vb`. This is the solution for any coordinate system, but first you have to choose a coordinate system.

Let's solve it first for Euclidian space...

Write this out for each component x and y. You now have two simultaneous equations in two variables and can solve for both `s` and `t`. They will collide if `s==t` (or is 'close'). Watch out for divide-by-zero when Va and Vb are parallel, and numerical instabilities.

For a spherical solution, consider two points moving on the circumferences of circles, the equations are the same form although A and B will be angles and Va and Vb will be angular velocities. To get the circles, calculate Euclidian Va and Vb instantaneously at any time, this taken with the Euclidian A and B (assuming Earth is centred at 0) tell you what plane you're working in, project into this plane to get a 2D problem for each plane separately.

Comment: I think he he wants the solution for a sphere (earth).

Comment: The information you are supplying is not enough. You have to specify what kind of lines the planes are going.

Comment: Absent of anything to the contrary, the lines are great circles because any other motion would require an intervening force which isn't mentioned. (If he'd said "satellites" instead of "aeroplanes" you wouldn't even think about it.)

Comment: Hi Curd, Spraff thanks for you answers. I have only lat,lon,direction,speed. Unfortunally my English are not very well so i dont know how to explain you more. I have 2 airplanes i know their coordinates speed and course and i want to check if there is any possible collision with this dara and in how much distance/ time

Comment: @spraff: yes, absent of anything to the contrary it would be more reasonable to assume a great circle path, but the expression "moving at x deg"  implies the contrary: constant bearing.

Comment: @Curd, perhaps it does to a helmsman, but to a mathematician like me it is an instantaneous description. It does *not* say "moving at **a sustained** x deg", therefore the bearing is subject to evolution along with everything else. You have to say what is held constant, not what is not, because the question is all about how things change. Change is the default behaviour. Migrate to english.stackoverflow? :-P

Comment: @spraff Look what i found. [This image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/99/testnc.png/) is from marine traffic. They have exactly what i want to do. Point A and Point B are Markers that have latitude,longitude,course,speed and there able to calculate the intersection point C! What formula they possible use? This is what i am asking for. do you know anything?

Comment: That image doesn't say what the projection is, so we can't say. For **sufficiently small** distances, by the way, it doesn't really matter and a linear approximation is good enough. How involved do you want to get? The earth as a non-sphere? Wind and currents? If it's for real-life applications then any technique with less error than that added by weather is good enough. I can't give an exact solution for a partially-specified problem. My posted answer is valid for the simplest interpretation. What about the answer don't you understand? I'm not sure you understand the question.